# JavaScript if-statement inside function to avoid division by zero NaN result?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, math, nan

I have this inside a function and the problem is one of the vars could be 0 and as we all know one can't divide by 0.

```
                    html += ('<div class="portlet banner-port" style="border-color: #2d0059;" class="panel-collapse collapse"> \
                            <div class="portlet-heading" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%), #2d0059;"> \
                                <div class="portlet-title" style="color:#ffffff;"> \
                                    <h4> \
                                    <i class="fa fa-link fa-fw"></i> '+jstext.language.custom_direct_link+' <span style="float:right"><span>'+jstext.language.custom_raw_visits+': '+resp.link.hits+'</span> <span>'+jstext.language.custom_transactions+': '+resp.link.conv+'</span> <span>'+jstext.language.custom_earnings+': '+resp.link.earnings+' €</span>  <span>EPC: '+(resp.link.earnings / resp.link.hits * 100).toFixed(2)+' €</span></span> \
                                    </h4> \
                                </div> \
                                    <div class="portlet-body"><label>'+jstext.language.marketing_target_url+':</label> \
                                        <textarea style="font-weight:normal !improtant;" id="direct-link-'+resp.data.id+'" rows="1" class="form-control">'+resp.direct_url+'</textarea> \
                                    </div> \
                            </div> \
                        </div>')
```

So in this case the JSON response **resp.link.hits** could be 0 and then the EPC is, as one should expect - NaN. I am having some basic syntax issues here, as I see it. Where do I declare to show 0 instead of NaN in this part:

```
<span>EPC: '+(resp.link.earnings / resp.link.hits * 100).toFixed(2)+' €</span>
```

I tried a couple of things like:

```
<span>EPC: '+if( resp.link.hits === 0 ){0} else {(resp.link.earnings / resp.link.hits * 100).toFixed(2)}+' €</span>
```

The above example with if-statement makes the whole code not work. I can't make it show 0.00 instead of NaN when dividing by 0. Any ideas? Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ternary operator as

```
<span>EPC: ' + ( resp.link.hits === 0  ? 0 : (data.earnings / data.hits * 100).toFixed(2) + ' €</span>
```

Comment: Tried it. Did not work. Btw syntax is condition ? exprT : exprF

Comment: Not sure but it screws the whole code. In the console, I see unexpected token }.

Comment: are you using vanilla js?

Comment: Using jQuery. This a part of DataTables init.

Comment: Updated the answer. Since there were curly braces, I thought you were using any JS template libs.

Comment: Now that works but you forgot to close one bracket between the 2) and the +. Thanks a lot! Chosen as answer!

Comment: How can I make it show 0.0000 instead of 0? I tried replacing the single zero with 0.0000 but it won't show this way. :)

Comment: `(0).toFixed(4)` would give you `0.0000`

Answer (score 1):

Try the ternary operator. The syntax is `expression ? trueValue : falseValue`

For example:

`<span>EPC: ' resp.link.hits === 0 ? 0 : (data.earnings / data.hits * 100).toFixed(2) + ' €</span>`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a flow control statement where you should have an expression.

In your code `if ...` doesn't *return* anything. Either you can reorganise your code or convert the `if` statement to a ternary operator `? :` like this:

```
resp.link.hits === 0 ? 0 : (data.earnings / data.hits * 100).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: I know, I know. Syntax is condition ? exprT : exprF and one should first state the true statement, then the false.